# Is there a way to make redirect work, instead of going back to form page after clicking browser's back button in PHP/WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, redirect, browser-history

I have a little problem. I created a form on a page, which sends data with $_POST. Data is being checked for errors and, if there are any, the page is going back to form with errors displayed. Errors are being get from $_POST variable. If I eventually input correct data I'm being redirected to homepage. But if I click the back button I can see the form again with the submission error (previously get from $_POST). Is it possible to go back but see homepage instead of login form with errors?

What's more, that situation doesn't happen when I input correct data straight away. If that happens, after clicking back button, no form visible, only homepage. Form (after clicking back button) is visible only if I input incorrect data first and the correct data.

This is in WordPRess, so you can see some WP related stuff in the code below.

Here is the login form:

```
echo 'Login Form';

$tw_email_err = '';
$tw_email     = '';

$tw_form        = tw_login_process(); // This function is below. It processes the form input.
$tw_email       = $tw_form['email'];
$tw_email_err   = $tw_form['message'];
$tw_consent_err = $tw_form['consent_msg'];


echo '<h2>Form</h2>
<form method="post">';

    wp_nonce_field( 'tw_login_form', 'tw_login_nonce' );

    echo '<input type="text" placeholder="e-mail" name="tw_email" value="' . esc_attr( $tw_email ) . '">
    <span class="tw-error">* ' . esc_html( $tw_email_err ) . '</span>
    <br><br>
    
    <input type="checkbox" id="tw_consent_check" name="tw_consent" value="on">
    <label for="tw_consent_check">Zgoda</label><br>
    <span class="tw-error">* ' . esc_html( $tw_consent_err ) . '</span>
    <br><br>
    <p><span class="error">* required field</span></p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>';
```

Form processing:

```
function tw_login_process() {

    $trzywu_users = tw_get_users(); // Get saved users from database, works OK.

    if ( isset( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ) && 'POST' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ) {

        $tw_check_email = ( isset( $_POST['tw_email'], $_POST['tw_login_nonce'] ) && wp_verify_nonce( sanitize_key( $_POST['tw_login_nonce'] ), 'tw_login_form' ) )
        ? sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_POST['tw_email'] ) )
        : '';

        $tw_check_consent = ( isset( $_POST['tw_consent'], $_POST['tw_login_nonce'] ) && wp_verify_nonce( sanitize_key( $_POST['tw_login_nonce'] ), 'tw_login_form' ) )
        ? sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_POST['tw_consent'] ) )
        : '';

        if ( $tw_check_email ) {

            $tw_check_result['email'] = $tw_check_email;

            if ( $trzywu_users && filter_var( $tw_check_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL ) && in_array( $tw_check_email, $trzywu_users, true ) ) {

                $tw_check_result['check']   = 'valid_existent';
                $tw_check_result['message'] = '';

            } elseif ( ! filter_var( $tw_check_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL ) ) {

                $tw_check_result['check']   = 'not_valid';
                $tw_check_result['message'] = 'Nieprawidłowy format adresu e-mail.';

            } elseif ( ! $trzywu_users || ! in_array( $tw_check_email, $trzywu_users, true ) ) {

                $tw_check_result['check']   = 'not_existent';
                $tw_check_result['message'] = 'Adres e-mail nie jest zarejestrowany.';

            }
        } else {

            $tw_check_result['email']   = '';
            $tw_check_result['check']   = 'not_set';
            $tw_check_result['message'] = 'Podaj adres e-mail';

        }

        $tw_check_result['consent'] = 'on' === $tw_check_consent ? 'consent_granted' : 'no_consent';

        if ( 'on' === $tw_check_consent ) {

            $tw_check_result['consent']     = 'consent_granted';
            $tw_check_result['consent_msg'] = '';

        } else {

            $tw_check_result['consent']     = 'no_consent';
            $tw_check_result['consent_msg'] = 'Wyraź zgodę na warunki Polityki Prywatności.';

        }

        return $tw_check_result;

    }
}
```

And finally redirections:

```
function tw_user_redirect() {

    global $tw_cookie_name; // This is cookie name for setcookie, don't worry about that.

    header( 'Cache-Control: no cache' ); // I'm using this to eliminate form resubmission error. Is it OK?
    session_cache_limiter( 'private_no_expire' );
    session_start();

    $tw_result     = tw_login_process(); //That's above form's processing.
    $tw_users      = tw_get_users(); // Just additional check, works OK.
    $tw_login_page = tw_get_login_page_id(); //this function gets login page ID, it works OK.

    if ( 'consent_granted' === $tw_result['consent'] && 'valid_existent' === $tw_result['check'] ) {

        if ( in_array( $tw_result['email'], $tw_users, true ) ) {

            $cokie_session_value = tw_password_hash( $tw_result['email'] );
            $_SESSION['user']    = $cokie_session_value;

            setcookie( $tw_cookie_name, $cokie_session_value, time() + ( 86400 * 7 ), '/' ); //Not important, I suppose?

        }

        wp_safe_redirect( home_url() );
        exit;

    }
    
    // This somehow doesn't work after clicking back button. It works in any other scenario though.
    if ( isset( $_SESSION['user'] ) && is_page( $tw_login_page ) ) {

        wp_safe_redirect( home_url() );
        exit;
    
    // This works as expected.
    } elseif ( ! isset( $_SESSION['user'] ) && ! is_page( $tw_login_page ) ) {

        wp_safe_redirect( get_permalink( $tw_login_page ) );
        exit;

    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'tw_user_redirect' );
```

Comment: The "back" button on a browser goes to the previous page. If that page was your form page, that's where it goes. The only way I know of to avoid this is to do all of your form handling with Ajax, so that there is no other page that the browser knows about.

Comment: So basically there is no way to achieve that, even when using $_SESSION to store form data and use it for validation instead of $_POST?

Comment: Your question said nothing about using the session or how that plays into what you want to accomplish. But the fundamental thing is that a browser will remember what pages you have seen, and the Back button takes you to the previous one.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I reworked the post title to better reflect the case and my posts's content. Anyways, any thoughts on how to make the redirect work properly in PHP but without involving AJAX, in my case?

Comment: Again, as I understand it, the behaviour you are seeing is How It Works. Form submissions that result in new pages being loaded with error messages in the form, are new pages that the browser remembers as part of the browsing history, and there is nothing you can do about that.

Comment: I'll rework it with Ajax then. Thank you!